# Android App not installed with USB debug

Tags: android, debugging, android-activity

I have a problem when I try to debug the App on my Phone. The App works, but It is not installed on the device. When I created the project I selected a project without Activity (option: "Add No Activity"). If I create an App with a blank Activity, this is installed when I launch the debug. I'm using Android Studio for the project.

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: What is your issue???

Comment: I need to keep my App installed on my phone after I load it with USB Debug. With current settings it launches on the Phone but it does not install in it

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to Specify Your App's Launcher Activity. You should put this line into your manifest in actvity tag like this, For more reference check this link [Specify Your App's Launcher Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#launching-activity)

```
        <activity
            android:name=".DemoActivity"    
            android:label="@string/app_name"    
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >    
            <intent-filter>    
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.categor.LAUNCHER" />    
            </intent-filter>    
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

Android Studio is stupid, it adviced me to write this in capital letters

```
<action android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.ACTION.MAIN" />    
<category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.LAUNCHER" />
```

instead

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```